# Invoke-RestMethod : Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook

Tags: powershell, t-sql, microsoft-teams

When I try to make a post request to teams webhook, I get this error message:

> Invoke-RestMethod : Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook.

Below is the code:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)
SET @cmd='Powershell.exe Invoke-RestMethod -Method post -ContentType ''Application/Json'' -Body ''{"text":"Hello"}'' -Uri <<webhook connector>>'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Comment: Have you tried running that command line in a console window? Powershell.exe has a [-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) parameter that you didn't specify.

Comment: It works fine in powershell command window but not in T-SQL. Added -Command flag as well but no luck

Comment: @vigneshsrinivasan Have you find any solution?